# Moment converts date as string for find query and object for aggregate query. How & Why?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, momentjs

When i use **find** query it returns date as object whereas while using **aggregate** it gives date as string after converting using **moment**. Why?

**find query**

```
this.find({},{
    "updated_at":1,
    "created_at":1,
},callback);
```

**aggregate query**

```
this.aggregate([{
    $project:{
        "updated_at" :1,
        "created_at" :1,
    }
}],callback);
```

Now when i convert the date to EST using moment i get the following results

```
// lets say query result is in dataArray

var created_at = moment(dataArray[0].created_at);
var created_at_est = created_at.clone().tz("America/New_York");
dataArray[0].created_at = created_at_est.format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss');
console.log(typeof(dataArray[0].created_at)); 
// result is string in aggregate query and object in find query
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening? Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `find` provides its results as Mongoose document instances (which can't be freely modified) while `aggregate` provides its results as plain objects (which can).

So if you want to modify the `created_at` field in your `find` results, tell Mongoose to provide plain objects instead by chaining a call to [`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean):

```
this.find({},{
    "updated_at":1,
    "created_at":1,
}).lean().exec(callback);
```

Comment: Hell of a info. Only you could have done it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

`format` method returns string. When you use `format` you want to show to user and is display function.

Comment: This is not the answer to my question :/

Comment: @shubhamsaini how do you test if it is string or object? in your sample you didn't explain so

Comment: sorry!! I have edited the last line of code. Please check it now.

Comment: @shubhamsaini in this line `dataArray[0].created_at = created_at_est.format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss');` you set it as string! `format` method returns string

Comment: if i go according to you then it should give string in both cases but it is not. It gives string only if i use aggregate query.

Comment: You check `created_at` just after fetching data. It should be object in both cases. And for sure, did you install `moment-timezone` npm module?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115941/discussion-between-shubham-saini-and-ebrahim-pasbani).